# How to rotate a particular element without affecting other elements in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to move the tank when the user pressed the right/left key. When I use `rotate()` it is affecting all the elements of the canvas. Is there a way to only move the third rectangle of the tank when the user presses the right or left key?

The goal is to change the angle by a certain amount on pressing the keys. I searched, but couldn't find something basic enough for me to understand how to implement it.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var rightPressed=false;
var leftPressed=false;
var score1=0;
var score2=0;
var turn=0;
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDownHandler,false);
document.addEventListener("keyup",keyUpHandler,false);
function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==37)
    leftPressed=true;
  else if(e.keyCode==39)
    rightPressed=true;
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==37)
    leftPressed=false;
  else if(e.keyCode==39)
    rightPressed=false;
}
function drawMountain() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(250, 400);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(250, 100, 500, 100, 500, 400);
  ctx.fillStyle="green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawTanks() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20,360,50,40);
  ctx.rect(620,360,50,40);
  ctx.rect(30,340,30,20);
  ctx.rect(630,340,30,20);
  ctx.rect(40,300,10,40);
  ctx.rect(640,300,10,40);
  ctx.fillStyle="blue";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

}
function rotateTank() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20,20,130,40);
  ctx.rect(560,20,130,40);
  ctx.fillStyle="green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle="white";
  ctx.font="20px Verdana";
  ctx.fillText('Player 1: '+ score1,28,45);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle="white";
  ctx.font="20px Verdana";
  ctx.fillText('Player 2: '+ score2,570,45);
  ctx.closePath();

}
function drawGame() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  drawMountain();
  drawTanks();
  rotateTank();
}
setInterval(drawGame,10);
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <center><canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="400"></canvas></center>
    <script src="game.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that we have two rectangles.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 10);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 20, 10);
```

And you want to rotate only the first one.

There are two ways to do it:

**Move the red rectangle after the blue one and rotate it**

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 20, 10);
ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 10);
```

**Just set ctx.rotate to a negative number (in our case -20) after the red rectangle**

```
ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 10);
ctx.rotate(-20*Math.PI/180); //This "resets" the rotation.
ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 20, 10);
```

Here's a code snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 10);
  ctx.rotate(-20*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00F";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 20, 10);
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100 style="border: 1px solid #000"></canvas>
```